# Ubuntu, Firefox can access internet, but terminal can't

Tags: linux, apt, ubuntu

I'm connected to university router, and I know they have many restrictions, but firefox is accessing the repo links without any issue, but the terminal can't.
How can I make the terminal use the same protocol as firefox?
Or, simply put, how can I update, install packages through apt?
Also, the ubuntu software package manager is throwing timeouts, I guess the internet is slow, but as I said, firefox is working just fine.

```
wadaane@wadaane-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt update
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Err:2 http://sy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:3 http://sy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err:4 http://sy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Reading package lists... Done
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://sy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://sy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://sy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
E: The repository 'http://sy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://sy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
E: The repository 'http://sy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Are you saying that you can use Firefox to reach the IP addresses that are showing `403 Forbidden` when using a terminal?

Comment: Yes, Exactly :(

Comment: Do you have a proxy set in Firefox? Does Firefox get redirected to a login page before you can access resources outside of the network (ie. Internet)?

Comment: no, no firefox proxy, no login.

Comment: This seems like a question that should be directed to your university's IT help. Otherwise there's always the really hard way around of creating a list of all the files you would need and then downloading them one by one. Also try wget directly and see what that does then try a terminal based browser like lynx.

Comment: IT department is not an option sadly, wget is working fine, so i guess the terminal is connected too, just the apt, i tried changing from http to https, and trying different repo, still nothing

Comment: If I insert this `http://91.189.91.26:80/` into the address line of my firefox I was redirected to `https://usn.ubuntu.com/` and I see the site **Ubuntu security notices**. Do you also see this site? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Comment: @Ingo Same here, i get redirected to https://usn.ubuntu.com/

Comment: That's strange. That means there is a firewall that can distinct between GET from *firefox* and GET from *apt*, maybe with deep packet inspection? Maybe, but can't really believe it.

Comment: Next step I would do is to look with *tcpdump* what's going out with *firefox* and with *apt* to see differences.

Comment: The firewall used is fortiguard.
Anyways, i gave up trying to use apt, i just download .deb files from packages.ubuntu.com, then install their dependecy one by one, also ubuntu sofware is working, i downloaded VLC from it last night.

Comment: @Ingo I added the tcpdump output in my question in askubuntu  
https://askubuntu.com/q/1099922/901922